# Legends not showing up correctly in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[image]

```
Rs= [20, 20, 20, 20]
Ls = [20, 30, 40, 50]
times = [t/10.0 for t in range(0,100)]
for R, L in zip(Rs, Ls):
    I = [m.exp((-R/L)*t)-1 for t in times]
    plt.plot(times,I)
    plt.legend(str(L))
```

I was expecting to get legends 20, 30, 40 and 50. Instead 5 and 0 show up. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `label` parameter of `plot()`, and call `legend()` outside the loop:

```
for R, L in zip(Rs, Ls):
    I = [m.exp((-R/L)*t)-1 for t in times]
    plt.plot(times, I, label=str(L))

plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]